# How to replace filed value in solrcloud

Tags: solrcloud

How to replace a filed value in `solrcloud`. e.g update a collection field value?

Answer (score 0):

The set modifier is basically used to do replace.Below is the snippet you can use to update the collection

Below is the following document exist in our collection

{
   "id":"mydoc",

"price":10,

"popularity":42,

}

And when we apply the update command

{
   "id":"mydoc",

"price":{"set":99},

"popularity":{"inc":20}

}

The resulting document will be as below.

{
   "id":"mydoc",

"price":99,

"popularity":62,

}

Comment: curl http://host:8987/solr/emp/update  --data-binary '<add><doc><field name="NUMBER">'55447854785'</field> <field name="acount" update="set">'3804948'</field></doc></add>'      not doing any thing,  is it ok?

Comment: What's the problem now?